# Aligning boxes(divs) of equal size in html symmetrically according to their number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to make an HTML page that contains a box at the top and a certain number of boxes being dynamically generated using jquery, the number of boxes at the bottom of top box can be 4 at max.

I want to align these boxes dynamically and symmetrically in the html page. I am using angularjs's ng-repeat to generate boxes. I want the sizes of the boxes to remain same but arrange them symmetrically on the html page.

currently i am using angular js to dynamically create boxes and align them using col-md class of bootstrap. but this makes the size of boxes to change when the number of boxes change.

html code

```
    <div id="header-wrapper" class="container vscrolling_container">
    <div id="header" class="container vscrolling_container">
        <div id="logo">
                        <h1 class="page-head-line" id="visionh"><a>Vision</a></h1>
                        <p id="visionp"><a rel="nofollow">{{visiontext}}</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row" id="missionstart">
        <div ng-class="missioncount[missions.length]" ng-repeat="mission in missions" style="opacity: 0.9">
            <div class="dashboard-div-wrapper" ng-class="bkclr[$index]">
                <h1 id="{{mission.id}}" style="color: #000">{{mission.missionInfo}}</h1>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
                    </div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="{{missioncontent.id}}" ng-repeat="missioncontent in mission.missionContent">
                        <p style="text-align: left">{{missioncontent.info}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

java script code

```
'use strict';

var mission_vision_mod = angular.module('myApp.mission_vision', ['ngRoute']);

mission_vision_mod.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/mission_vision', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/mission_vision/mission_vision.html',
    controller: 'mission_visionCtrl'
  });
}]);

mission_vision_mod.controller('mission_visionCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.visiontext = "Here is the content of vision";
        $scope.bkclr = ['bk-clr-one','bk-clr-two','bk-clr-three','bk-clr-four'];
        $scope.progressbar = ['progress-bar-warning','progress-bar-danger','progress-bar-success','progress-bar-primary'];
        $scope.missioncount = ['col-md-0','col-md-12','col-md-6','col-md-4','col-md-3','col-md-2.5','col-md-2'];

        $http.get('m_id.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.missions = data;
            $scope.len = data.length;
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Add code instead of images

Comment: i am creating the mission and vision page for a dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapz927/t1LeL4y3/)

HTML Content:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related CSS:

```
.container div {
    height: 100px;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.content {
    text-align: center;
}
.contentBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Caution: I have used plain CSS for this demo.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do this

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.top,
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.top {
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bb38p3nf/1/)